# Display random gallery images and its parent post title leading to parent post permalink

Tags: attachments, gallery

I usually have a gallery in posts. I want to display random image and its post-title from a random published post which can lead to permalink like related posts below a post.

I used this code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'orderby' => 'rand'
); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
```

It displays image attachments which are not published from media library. And shows url as ../wp-content/uploads/2013/01/attachment-name not as abc.com/post-name/attachment-name.

Please suggest!!

Thanks.

Comment: `'post_status' => 'published'` ? you are using `null` by the way...

Comment: tried 'publish' not working!!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want this: below your post you want to have three links to different posts, and each link should have a picture of the gallery of the linked post to it?

Comment: Yes, fishci. 3 links to different random posts with their title but random gallery image as thumbnail pointing to post-permalink!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is that you have to search for posts first, and afterwards to images to the post.

In my code I included a parameter `exclude` to ensure the current post is not delivered again.

Please keep in mind that if a post has no Image, none will be shown. Also, I did not include stylings or fallbacks, if there are no posts to show or something like that - but that should be no problem to work out.

Have fun!

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'exclude' => get_the_ID()
); 
$relatedposts = get_posts( $args );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $relatedposts as $related ) {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_parent' => $related->ID,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    $thisimage = $attachments[0];

    echo '<li>';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thisimage->ID, 'thumbnail' );
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $related->ID ) . '">' . $related->post_title . '</a>';
    echo '</li>';

}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: wow, it works wonderfully, thanks fischi!! I have included all fallbacks. No problem.